# Message: session not created exception from chrome not reachable

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running Chrome headless with Python, Selenium and also multithreading in order to open multiple instances of Chrome.

It seems like I have the same issue as others on StackOverflow, but with a different error from what was treated here on the site (now: Chrome not reachable)

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from chrome not reachable
  (Session info: headless chrome=60.0.3112.113)
```

The problem is that this error pops randomly and stops the execution of the script.

Edit: This is the main part of the code where I multithread a function named `scrape`, which is, of course, a scraper.

```
for chunk in chunks(LIST, 50):
    pool = ThreadPool(max_number_of_browsers)

    records = pool.map(scrape, chunk)

    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
```

`chunks(list, chunk_size)` is a function that breaks a bigger list into chunks of specified size.
`max_number_of_browsers` is the number of threads I specify to use.

Comment: Can we get to see your code trial please?

Comment: I added the main part of the code. The scrape function is kind of messy, but it ends in `driver.close(); driver.quit()`